# How to set height of content with jQuery – cut off in small window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, height

I'm having trouble getting this to work. Currently, it's resizing section[role="main"] to the height properly, but when you resize the window to a small size, it cuts off.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('section[role="main"]') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('section[role="main"]') .css({'height': (($(window).height()))+'px'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm also wondering how I would compensate for the height of the footer? As of now, it is pushing the footer off-screen.

Thanks for any help!

So it should look something like this, **Patrick (Updated)**?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(window).resize(function(){
                var winheight = $(window).height();
                var heightMinusFooter = winheight - jQuery("#footer").height();
                $('section[role="main"]') .css({'height': heightMinusFooter+'px'});
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the footer height from the window height then apply.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var winheight = $(window).height();
    var heightMinusFooter = winheight - jQuery("#footer").height();
    $('section[role="main"]') .css({'height': heightMinusFooter+'px'});
});
```

Comment: I've included how I did it just to confirm, don't have it working quite yet. Is this correct?

Comment: Do I have to specify a height for the footer in CSS? It didn't seem to help when I tried.

Comment: the variables for getting the heights have to be inside the resize function, and you are using jQuery('footer') which wont work because there is no tag named footer, give whatever element you are using for the footer a id like "footer" and use jQuery("#FooterIdThatYouUsed") and no you dont have to specify a height, the .height call will get the computed height for the element

Comment: and you dont use min-height use height or max-height.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I appreciate the help – still not quite working. I've updated the code in my post... is that correct? Sorry. I'm not very jQuery-savvy.

Comment: You may find yourself needing to resize JSFiddle for it to show up. It's not working on load.

Comment: Also... I have it working with "min-height" on the real site, but not with height or max-height. If I don't use min-height, the footer clips the content and the page doesn't scroll properly when resized small.